# Cannot get service to work in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I cannot get the "posts" service to work in the "angular services" section of this tutorial from thinkster.io:

https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/

Why won't the new posts show up when created?  I used Yeoman to set up the app.  Here is my code:

app.js

```
use strict';

/**
* @ngdoc overview
* @name meanStackTutorialApp
* @description
* # meanStackTutorialApp
*
* Main module of the application.
*/
angular.module('meanStackTutorialApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize',
'ngTouch'

 ])
 .config(function ($routeProvider) {

 $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
    controller: 'AboutCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });

 });
```

main.js

```
angular.module('mainMod').factory('posts', [function(){
var o = {
    posts : []
        };
    return o;
}]);
var MainMod = angular.module('mainMod')
   .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'posts', function ($scope, posts) {

    $scope.posts = posts.posts;


    $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
  post.upvotes += 1;
};

$scope.addPost = function(){
    if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }

    $scope.posts.push({title: $scope.title, 
                      link: $scope.link,
                     upvotes: 0});

    $scope.title = '';
    $scope.link = '';
    };
}]);
```

main.html:

```
<div class="jumbotron">

</div>

<form ng-submit="addPost()">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title"></input>
  <br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Link" ng-model="link"></input>
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Post</button>
</form>

<div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: '-upvotes'">
  <span ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)">^</span>
  {{post.title}} - 
    <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
    {{post.title}}
  </a>
  <span ng-hide="post.link">
    {{post.title}}
  </span> 
  upvotes: {{post.upvotes}}
</div>

<div class="row marketing">h

</div>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up { cursor:pointer } </style>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="meanStackTutorialApp">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div class="header">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">meanStackTutorial</a>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
              <li><a ng-href="#/about">About</a></li>
              <li><a ng-href="#/">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> from the Yeoman team</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
     <script>
       !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
       (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
       r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
       }(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
         <script src="scripts/services/mainModServices.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Anything displayed in the browser's developer tools console?

Comment: I cannot see it, have you referenced the controller in your html. You have ```<body ng-app="meanStackTutorialApp">``` but i cant see anywhere that you have referenced ```ng-controller="MainCtrl"```

Comment: in fact it looks as if you havent even referenced the angular app ```mainMod``` which the posts factory is related to

Comment: I thought that I don't need to use ng-controller = "MainCtrl" in the HTML because the routing in the app.js config function handles that.  Is this right?